# How i add an addListener to GOOGLE MAPS to get MapType

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How i add an addListener to GOOGLE MAPS to get MapType

Comment: what event do you want to listen for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "maptypechanged", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getCurrentMapType();
    // ...
})
```

Comment: if you are using V3 of API,                    google.maps.event.addListener($.nmap.map,'maptypeid_changed', function(){ alert($.nmap.map.getMapTypeId() );});

Answer (score 2):

ok! i found it myself 
map.getCurrentMapType().getName();

Answer (score 0):

This works better. Test with alert()

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "maptypechanged", function() {
    var newMapType = map.getCurrentMapType().getName(true);   
    //alert(newMapType);
    ....
})
```